# Change border of facebook like icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, facebook, facebook-like

I can't for the life of me figure out how to do it with just CSS, I think because their javascript overrides it, even if I use !important. Therefore I tried loading the javascript using JQuery's $.getScript() function but then it doesn't even work.

I would like it just to be a simple black border.

URL: http://www.imvu-e.com/products/sro/

Comment: changing facebook's plugins is against their policy...

Comment: It changed doing it through firebug doing it on this element: .button_count a.connect_widget_like_button - i added a 1pc black border. Is that the line you tried it on? Make sure your css is loading after the FB button is being called.

Comment: Try `border: 1px solid black`. It looks like you're just changing the color.

Comment: Yes I can change it using firebug or chrome too, but cannot get the CSS to load after the FB button. Thats the issue I think. I have tried `border: 1px solid black`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to override facebook's css, I just ended up wrapping a div around the button and put a border around that. This code worked pretty good to get an effect I wanted:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid black; background: #ECEEF5 url('http://i.imgur.com/y8DyO.png'); width: 49px; height: 20px; border-radius: 3px;">
     <!--  INSERT FACEBOOK LIKE DIV HERE -->
</div>
```

Note: `background: #ECEEF5 url('http://i.imgur.com/y8DyO.png');` was added so that the div has a background the same as the like button so for that split second while javascript is running, you won't see a flicker from no background to facebook's #ECEEF5.

Result:

[image: black bordered facebook like]